# Flurry Analytics crashing when "Run" in Android emulator but not when "Debugged" in emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, flurry

As per the title, I have an application which makes use of the [Flurry Analytics](http://www.flurry.com/flurry-analytics.html) library for Android.  I've followed their [basic steps](http://support.flurry.com/index.php?title=Analytics/GettingStarted/Android) to integrate analytics into my app.  If I *Debug* my app in the Android emulator, everything works fine.  If I *Run* my app in the Android emulator on the other hand, Flurry seems to crash it.  Here is the output from logcat:

```
10-19 16:03:14.004: E/AndroidRuntime(385): FATAL EXCEPTION: FlurryAgent  
10-19 16:03:14.004: E/AndroidRuntime(385): java.lang.NullPointerException  
10-19 16:03:14.004: E/AndroidRuntime(385):  at com.flurry.android.FlurryAgent.b(SourceFile:2188)  
10-19 16:03:14.004: E/AndroidRuntime(385):  at   com.flurry.android.FlurryAgent.a(SourceFile:68)  
10-19 16:03:14.004: E/AndroidRuntime(385):  at com.flurry.android.e.run(SourceFile:1420)  
10-19 16:03:14.004: E/AndroidRuntime(385):  at   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)  
10-19 16:03:14.004: E/AndroidRuntime(385):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)  
10-19 16:03:14.004: E/AndroidRuntime(385):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)  
10-19 16:03:14.004: E/AndroidRuntime(385):  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
```

Curiously, this problem only seems to occur when I run in an Android 2.2 (Froyo) Virtual Device, whereas if I run it in an Android 4.1 Virtual Device, it is fine.  Unfortunately I don't have immediate access to a real Android 2.2 device to test on.

Can anyone suggest what might be going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a similar problem on **Flurry SDK**, with version **3.0.4**;
Flurry library crashes on start both emulators and real devices with android version < **2.3** (I checked it on real device 2.2, and 2.1, 2.2 - emulators).

Fixed on release **3.0.5**, see changelog:

> Version 3.0.5- 10/26/2012
>   ●
>   added fix to prevent crashing of bad phone ids in AndroidSDK 2.2

Comment: I am having this problem on Google TV.  I have already updated to their latest jar file.  What next???

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there is some sort of problem with the latest Flurry SDK. 
The exception shows up on real devices too (android 2.2 and release only).

What I did was to use an older version of the Flurry SDK which works fine.

Comment: Hi Bogdan, what version of Flurry did you used ?

Comment: @zasadnyy I used SDK version 2.2.5 that was working fine in an older project.

Answer (score 1):

I also had this issue, but it seems to have been fixed with the release of the sdk 3.0.5

Answer (score 0):

Happens to me on Flurry 3.4.0. Crashes on:

```
FlurryAgent.onStartSession( parent , FLURRY_API_KEY);
```

Where `parent` is of `FragmentActivity`.

The only thing that worked for me is to call the method with app context:

```
FlurryAgent.onStartSession( parent.getApplicationContext() , FLURRY_API_KEY);
```