# Android - flurry crash with exception

Tags: android, flurry

I recently got this crash report from what looks like a flurry library crash on my app:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
        at com.flurry.android.FlurryAgent.a(SourceFile:87)
        at com.flurry.android.d.run(SourceFile:1152)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
```

Has anyone seen this or is familiar with it? I don't even know what caused it as it does not say what file caused the problem.

Any thoughts on how to prevent this?

Comment: Have a look at a similar error: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13360585/803896

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to update to SDK v3.0.5 which includes a fix to prevent crashing of bad phone ids in AndroidSDK 2.2.

(Full disclosure: I work in the Support team at Flurry)